# Understanding a derivative in a biology article

Tags: derivatives, applications, biology

From [this biology article](http://www.genetics.org/content/147/2/879.short) (5th page, right column)

They have...

$$1-P_t ≈ 1-(1+s)P_{t+1}+\frac{p_{t+1}^2}{2}$$

and they conclude that...

$$\frac{dP}{dt} ≈ -sP + \frac{P^2}{2}$$

I don't really understand this link. How did they do that?

Comment: What page? ${}{}$

Comment: @anorton see update at the first line of my post.

Comment: $P_{t+1}-P_t = -sP_{t+1}+P^2_{t+1}/2$. The left part is "something like" derivative (see numerical approximations of derivative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $1$ is small when compared to $t$, so they read $P_{t+1}$ as $P_t + dP/dt$. The first equation then becomes
$$1 - P \approx 1 - (1 + s)(P + dP/dt) + \tfrac{1}{2}(P + dP/dt)^2.$$
Solving this for $dP/dt$ and ignoring the term $(dP/dt)^2$ gives their result.

Comment: Actually, the approximation $1\ll t$ is quite irrelevant here and there is no convincing reason to "ignore" $(dP/dt)^2$.